# how to get device user name other information in iphone?

Tags: iphone

In my iphone application i want user device all the settings information using code.
i.e. User name,Device OS,Device Version etc....

IS it possible using code or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `[UIDevice currentDevice]`?  Have a look at [this](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006902-CH3-DontLinkElementID_4).

Answer (score 1):

Apple has yanked access to all of the unique info from public interfaces - including the device unique ID.

Perhaps your best bet is to provide your User the opportunity to input into your app whatever it is they might wish you to be able to know - and conceivably share.

It is possible to create a unique ID:

```
CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
NSString* myuniqueID = (__bridge NSString*)CFUUIDCreateString (kCFAllocatorDefault, theUUID);
```

and save it for later use in your app's NSUserDefaults